# Private to private network address translation

Tags: nat

I need a black box that will translate 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2. Can a NAT router do this?

The problem that I am trying to solve: I have 2 devices with identical IPs of 192.168.1.1. The devices have dongles that fix their IP to this value. I need to communicate to them separately via telnet for testing.

Comment: Since a NAT wall would require both sides to be differant LANs, you would have to use two NAT walls, such that 192.168.0 <-> 10.0.0.0 <-> 192.168.1.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/389306/whats-the-best-way-to-accomodate-multiple-devices-that-all-want-to-use-the-same

Comment: Frank thanks for the suggestion. I wonder if an inexpensive linux router and iptables port forwarding could also work?

Comment: Building on Frank's suggestion, I think it's easiest for me to have a separate NIC for device 2 with a NAT router that can translate 10.0.0.1<->192.168.1.1. This might not be the best solution though if there are a large number of devices to connect this way.